# Sqlite table is not being created

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

My database is created but table is not being created. The `db.insert()` function returns a positive integer in the log, but the table is not being created. No errors are shown in the logs. The SQL query also runs fine on sqlite browser.I am using Android Studio 3.6.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: called");

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    }

    public void OpenLibrary(View view){
        Log.d(TAG, "OpenLibrary: called");
        Intent  intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,LibraryActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Library.class

```
public class LibraryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_library);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.lib_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.createLib:
                Intent intent = new Intent(LibraryActivity.this,NewLibrary.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

NewLibary.class

```
public class NewLibrary extends AppCompatActivity {
    AppCompatEditText Xet,Yet,Aet,Bet;
    AppCompatButton SaveBtn;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    private static final String TAG = "NewLibrary";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_library);
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);

        Xet = findViewById(R.id.etX);
        Yet = findViewById(R.id.etY);
        Aet = findViewById(R.id.etA);
        Bet = findViewById(R.id.etB);

        SaveBtn = findViewById(R.id.Save);
    }

    public void Save(View view){
        int a = Integer.parseInt(Aet.getText().toString());
        int b  = Integer.parseInt(Bet.getText().toString());
        int x = Integer.parseInt(Yet.getText().toString());
        int y = Integer.parseInt(Xet.getText().toString());

        dbHelper.insertIntoDb(a,b,x,y);
    }
}
```

And finally DbHelper.class

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "motionAppDatabase.db";
    public static final String VAlUE_TABLE_NAME = "MotionTable";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_A = "a";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_B = "b";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_X = "x";
    public static final String VALUE_COLUMN_Y = "y";
    private static final String TAG = "DbHelper";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "DbHelper: called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: database onCreate() called ");
        String CREATE_TABLE_ST = "CREATE TABLE "+VAlUE_TABLE_NAME+
                "("+VALUE_COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+VALUE_COLUMN_A+" INTEGER,"
                +VALUE_COLUMN_B+" INTEGER,"+VALUE_COLUMN_X +" INTEGER,"+VALUE_COLUMN_Y +" INTEGER"+")";
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: "+CREATE_TABLE_ST);

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade: called");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+VAlUE_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertIntoDb(int a,int b,int x, int y){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DbHelper.VALUE_COLUMN_A,a);
        contentValues.put(DbHelper.VALUE_COLUMN_B,b);
        contentValues.put(DbHelper.VALUE_COLUMN_X,x);
        contentValues.put(DbHelper.VALUE_COLUMN_Y,y);
        long rowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(VAlUE_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        Log.d(TAG, "Save: "+rowId);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the table is not created? If `insert()` returns a positive value, the insert was successful and that tells the table has been created.

Comment: Thats what i have explained above,I copy the database file and open it in a sqlite browers no tables is shown there

Comment: it could be Android not flushing the buffer, try force close your app, or better yet, restart your Android and see if the table exist on the file

Comment: problem solved i had not closed the database after the insert() function.Closing that solved my problem

Comment: That's one way to solve it. Another would be to not only copy the .db but its .wal temp file too.

Answer (score 1):

I had not closed the database after the database insert() function.Closing the database after insert() created the table.

```
sqLiteDatabase.insert(MotionContract.MotionEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
 sqLiteDatabase.close();
```